# How to sort list of lists according to length of sublists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have the following list

```
a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['m', 'n'], ['o']]
```

I would like to sort the list based on the length of their sub lists.
The result should be like:

```
a = [['o'],['d','e'],['m', 'n'],['a', 'b', 'c'],['f', 'g', 'h'], ['i','j','k','l']]
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use `key` parameter available in `sort` and `sorted`. It specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element

```
In [6]: a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['m', 'n'], ['o']]

In [7]: a.sort(key=len)

In [8]: print a
[['o'], ['d', 'e'], ['m', 'n'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']]
```

Comment: Which is not a key whatsoever, but brilliant anyway :)

Comment: Simple thing but didn't get idea Tnq Alik :)

Comment: @rajeshv90 `sort` now compares not sublists, but their lengths (values of `len(sublist)`)

Comment: A small tweak to sort the array in decreasing order of subarray lengths:



`a.sort(key=len, reverse=True)`

Answer (score 7):

can be done by

```
sorted(a, key=len)
```

Comment: you must explain, wt you doing, that will OP